# 無限ループに条件分岐を設定したが想定外の動作となる

Tags: c

#### 質問概要

無限ループの中で条件分岐を行って `break` する処理を書いています。
この時、`if (x != 0)` だと動作するが、`if (x = 0)` とした場合はうまく動作しません。
それぞれの動作の違いを教えていただきたいです。詳細は後述します。

#### 実装したい処理

1. `scanf` で整数を入力させ、これまで入力された整数の総和を表示する。
   (状態保持用の変数に初期値1を入れているので、最初は1 + (入力された整数)から始まる)
2. `scanf` で0が入力された場合は無限ループを `break` し、プログラムを終了する。

#### 質問詳細

下記コードは想定した動作をしますが、`if (x = 0)` に書き換えると上手く動作しません。

**コード全文:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int m = 1; //状態保持用変数

int sum(int n) {
    m += n;
    return m; 
}

int main(void) {
    int x; //入力値受け取り用変数

    while (1) {
        printf("n? ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x != 0) {
            printf("%d\n", sum(x));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**出力結果:**

```
n? 4
5
n? 5
10
n? 0
ubuntu@dev01: ~$
```

**if(x = 0)に書き換え:**

```
        if (x = 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", sum(x));
        }
```

**if (x = 0)の場合の出力結果:**

```
n? 4
1
n? 5
1
n? 0
1
...
...
```

条件をひっくり返しているだけなので動作すると思ったのですが、想定外の動作となってしまいました。

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、それぞれの動作が異なる原因を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `if (x = 0)`の`x = 0`は、変数`x`に`0`を代入する式です。`if (x != 0)`の「逆」は、`if (x == 0)`になります。

Comment: 初歩的なミスで恥ずかしいです…基本を学び直さないといけませんね。ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = 0` では `x` にゼロを入れてしますからです。
`x == 0` の間違いではないですか、論理式ですよね。